# Helsinki MOOC.fi keeps telling me "IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0" but I always get the desired output..?

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist

Here is my program...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();

    while (true) {
        int number = Integer.valueOf(scanner.nextLine());
        if (number <= -1) {
            break;
        }
        list.add(number);
    }
    int biggest = list.get(0);              

    for (int i = 0; i <= list.size()-1; i++) {        
        int small = list.get(i);            
        if (small > biggest) {               
            biggest = small;
        }

    }
    System.out.println("The greatest number: " + biggest);

}
```

It does what the project is asking me to do. I just have to iterate through the ArrayList and print out the greatest in the list. It works! but, when I submit the project, I just get back an "Index out of bounds exception". Why does this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int number = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
```

Use `.parseInt()` to get int value from the String. Not `.valueOf()` when working with primitives.

From the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf(java.lang.String)):

> `.valueOf()` method returns an Integer object equal to the value of:

```
new Integer(Integer.parseInt(s))
```

---

If the first number entered is `-1`, then `list.get(0);` will throw the same exception. You need to put a check like:

```
if (list.size() > 0) {
    int biggest = list.get(0);

    for (int i = 0; i <= list.size()-1; i++) {
        int small = list.get(i);
        if (small > biggest) {
            biggest = small;
        }

    }
    System.out.println("The greatest number: " + biggest);
} else {
    // handle case - first number entered was -1
}
```

Comment: Where does that go? I tried putting it first within the while loop and before the while loop. Now, the program crashes.

Comment: @TibetanMassive - check my edit and you will understand

Comment: I do! Is that a pretty common way to fix that issue?

Comment: Mostly. I would take the code out in a method, and if the list.size is 0, then I would return immediately printing the message that there are no elements in the list.